# Route [product.store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hijabrent\resources\views\product\create.blade.php)

Tags: java, php, html, css, laravel

I'm using Laravel

This is `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/index', function () {
    return view('/product/index');
});
Route::get('/create', function () {
    return view('/product/create');
});
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('products.store');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::view('/admin', 'admin');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:seller'], function () {
    Route::view('/seller', 'seller');


});
```

This is form call create:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @include('admin.includes.sidebar_admin')
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Create products</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


       <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title...">
        </div>
```

When I click submit, it shows error. I want to create a new product and the detail store in database.

Please Help.

Comment: `->name('products.store');` vs `route('product.store')` **product** does not equal **products** (plural, one has an `s`, the other doesn't.) Voting to close as a typo; incorrect pluralization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typo error. You have add same name as route name in the form action.

```
     <form action="{{route('products.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title...">
        </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, please avoid answering typo questions. They don't help anyone, and users with enough reputation can vote to close them as "Off-topic"

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your form

```html
<form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title...">
        </div>
     </form>
```

Here you have "product.store" as action for your form and in your web.php it is "products.store"